# How to plot a variable with selected number of rows using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, line

A sample of my dataframe (speed) is as below with 45122 observations.

```
         A         B          C      
    1 0.06483121 0.08834364 0.05814113 
    2 0.06904103 0.13169238 0.06082291 
    3 0.05556961 0.09767185 0.06039383 
    4 0.06483121 0.13388726 0.05996474 
    5 0.06651514 0.11632827 0.04891578 
    6 0.06904103 0.11687699 0.05953565 
    ...
    ......       
45122 0.06212749 0.08307191 0.07422524
```

I can create a simple plot by selecting number of observation I like using code below:

( temporal cyclic pattern- speed shown in the y axis, 0 to 500 in the x axis)

```
plot(speed[1:500,3], type="l", ylab="speed", xlab="unit time")
```

I am trying to do the same with ggplot2, but it's giving me a histogram.

How do I do the similar plot using ggplot?

Comment: Perhaps `speed1 <- speed[1:500,3, drop=FALSE]; ggplot(speed1, aes(x=1:nrow(speed1), y=C))+geom_line()`

Comment: It gave me this error:

`Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = 1:500, y = function (object, contr, how.many,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 500, 0` @akrun

Comment: I am not getting any error with  `ggplot2_1.0.1`

Comment: can you show the `str(speed)`

Comment: `'data.frame': 45122 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: num  0.0648 0.069 0.0556 0.0648 0.0665 ...
 $ B  : num  0.0883 0.1317 0.0977 0.1339 0.1163 ...
 $ C: num  0.0581 0.0608 0.0604 0.06 0.0489 ...`
@akrun Thanks

Comment: The `str` looks OK to me.  I did tested the code with the example you provided and it is working for me.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my ggplot2 package to 1.0.1., But it's still giving me the same error. weird.. @akrun

Comment: Can you try on a fresh R console

Comment: I've tried. Same error kept coming...@akrun

Comment: No idea what is the problem.  Here is a reproducible example `set.seed(24);speed <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(45122*3), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])));
speed1 <- speed[1:500,3, drop=FALSE];ggplot(speed1, aes(x=1:nrow(speed1), y=C))+geom_line() + ylab('speed') +xlab('unit time')`  It is working for me

Comment: That plotted beautifully! Thanks! I'm new to ggplot2, I don't really know what does what yet in the code, I'll teach myself soon. You may post that in the answer:-) @akrun

Comment: The first code Akrun gave in the comment now worked. I made a silly typo, pardon me :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We `subset` the first 500 rows and the third variable ('C') using `[`.  Note that we have to add `drop=FALSE` as the default is `drop=TRUE`.  According to `?"["`, if `drop=TRUE`, the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension, i.e. in this case a `vector`.

```
 speed1 <- speed[1:500,3, drop=FALSE]
```

We specify the 'x' (`1:nrow(speed1)`) and 'y' variables in the `aes`, use `geom_line()` for a `line` plot and `xlab` and `ylab` to specify the labels for 'x axis' and 'y axis'.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(speed1, aes(x=1:nrow(speed1), y=C))+
                    geom_line() + 
                    ylab('speed') +
                    xlab('unit time')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
speed <- as.data.frame(matrix(abs(rnorm(45122*3)), ncol=3,
          dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])))
```

Comment: Why is it plotting wrongly with negative values? I don't have any negative fields. Is it because of the y=C? @akrun

Comment: @Maisarah  It was just an example.  I could have created with `abs(rnorm(45122*3))`